# aber follows subject when acting as the conjunction "bin mir aber nicht sicher"

Tags: conjunction

I was reading a German text earlier, and in the dialogue was a character who said:

> Ich vermute, dass er lügt, bin mir aber nicht sicher.
>
> > **I suspect that he's lying, but I can't be sure**

Now, I was confused about the position of the "aber".

As "aber" would be a conjunctions in the sentence, I expected it to be the word following the comma:

> Ich vermute, dass er lügt, aber (ich) bin mir nicht sicher.

I worked out that "sicher sein" means to be certain and "mir" is simply the object the verb refers to.

However, I can't (as hard as I try) seem to work out why "aber" comes way after the comma.

Another example that also confused me:

> Ich war noch nie in Italien, kann es mir aber als ein schönes Land vorstellen.
>
> > **I've never been to Italy, but I can imagine it as a beautiful country**
>
> or more literally
>
> > I've never been to Italy, but I imagine it is a beautiful country.

Why is the "aber" displaced so far down the sentence, even though it is a conjunctions?

Comment: You've recognized the ideosyncratic behaviour of *aber*: it ocurs within the co-ordinated clause even though it still functions as a cordination. That's all you need to know to use it successfully. I'm afraid asking "*Why* does this word behave like that and not others?" is no more useful than asking "Why does *aber*  begin with an *a*?"

Comment: The word *aber* is either a conjunction, an adverb or a particle. Choose your poison. English has those, too: See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_adverb

Comment: Note your chosen positions of the conjunction are not the only valid ones: Ich war noch nie in Italien, aber kann...", "Ich war noch nie in Italien, kann mir aber...." and "Ich war noch nie in Italien, kann aber mir..."  all work and are valid. German is much more flexible in possible word order than English.

Comment: Is *mir* the subject? That would explain why it would be there at all when the English equivalent isn't reflexive and a non-reflexive variant exists in German as well. I would have said *I* was the subject, but am not sure anymore, I am myself really not sure. I'm gonna have me some sure tee now.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was: in this case **aber** appears as an **adverb**.

Look up: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aber

“Usage:

Unlike most other conjunctions, aber need not be the first word of a clause: Ich bin dafür, er aber lehnt es ab. — “I’m in favour, but he rejects it.” In such a construction, aber might be considered an adverb, though the usual interpretation is that it is still a conjunction”

Comment: You could also say that a conjunction is an adverb (for the phrase, for the verb of a phrase). You can also say "Er lehnt es aber ab". The concept of a conjunction is not very meaningful, if you think of a Normal form composed of AND, OR and NOT, and sentences as implicitly bound by AND or OR, depending on whether you have an anaphora. Anyhow, this use of "aber" exists in English too: "He is but the only one"; "all but him", the latter is a preposition, apparently.

Comment: I just looked up `aber` in the Duden dictionary. `Aber` is indeed an adverb in this example. As native German speaker and can say that `[ich] bin mir aber nicht sicher` feels more natural than `aber [ich] bin mir nicht sicher` - especially in spoken language.

Comment: The mother of a friend of mine used to say: „Es changiert nüt!“ („It doesn‘t change anything!“